# Paperclip copy image to another model without original file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I know that I can copy an image from one model to another model like this:

```
model2.image = model1.file
```

However, my first model does not store the *:original* file. So this can't work.

So I tried like this:

model2.image = File.open(model1.file.url(:high))

But the file is not found but really present.

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   //s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com...

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

You're openning a remote file in the wrong:

```
require 'open-uri'

path = "https://s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com..."
model2.image = open(path).read
```

`File.open` doesn't suppose to be used with remote files for security reason.

Comment: I have the exact same issue using open-uri. `image.file = open(photo.file.url(:high)).read` `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - //s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/app-dev/usr/photos/files/000/000/000/017/high/file.jpg`